# What word or phrase describes "badly executed but ultimately successful"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Like the title says, what word or phrase describes a task that was badly executed, but the task was completed anyway?

Comment: Why do you think the author used so many words?

Comment: The author is me. This is for an essay I am writing and I was wondering if there was any word or phrase that can convey the meaning without as many words.

Comment: Maybe a “botched job.” But your title and headline are not the same. The title sounds like a movie review, where the movie is not done well but still is effective for the audience. Many tasks are executed badly but completed—like frying an egg.  Or doing a gymnastic routine on the high bars.

Comment: [In the UK] It was cobbled together, thrown together, knocked up, done on a wing and a prayer. It's held together with spit and baling wire/chewing gum, not pretty but it works, a bit bish bosh, a bit kick-bollock-and-scramble, a bit Heath Robinson, a bit Amateur Hour, a poor thing but mine own, not exactly state-of-the-art, not going to win the Turner Prize (but...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["more by luck than judgement"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/more-by-luck-than-judgment)

> by chance and not because of any special skill:
> "You did amazingly well to get the ball in." "Oh, it was more by luck than judgment."